# Bind a Class with Properties and List to WinForms DatagridView

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, datagridview, bindinglist

I've got the following problem:

Ive got a Core-Class containing BindingLists for Produkt and Gruppe as public static.

class Core:

```
    private static BindingList<Produkt> _produkte;
    private static BindingList<Gruppe> _gruppen;
    private static BindingList<Tag> _tage;
 public Core() //operating class
    {
        Produkte = new BindingList<Produkt>();
        Gruppen = new BindingList<Gruppe>();
        Tage = new BindingList<Tag>();
    }
```

Class Produkt:

```
    private int _id; //Product attributes
    private string _name;
    private Gruppe _gruppe;
    private double _kohlenhydrate_je_100g;
    private double _eiweiss_je_100g;
    private double _fett_je_100g;
    private double _alkoholgehalt;
    private double _kcal;
```

Class Gruppe:

```
    private int _id; //group attributes. Each product has got 0-1 group
    private string _name;
```

Every variable got a Property with both public Set & get.
I need to get the BindingList _produkte displayed in another forms DataGridView, but im not able to fill the Combobox with all items of Gruppe.
All items were displayed and the selected value for Display is in the combobox as well as all other possible values, but im unable to switch the gruppe in my DatagridViewComboBox, nor am I allowed to add a new line to the Datagrid.

```
public Produktpflege()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].ValueType = typeof(int);
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].ValueType = typeof(string);
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(String); //changed Gruppe to string @ChetanRanpariya's comment, but no change in behaviour
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].ValueType = typeof(double);
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].ValueType = typeof(double);
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].ValueType = typeof(double);
        dataGridView1.Columns[6].ValueType = typeof(double);
        dataGridView1.Columns[7].ValueType = typeof(double);
        gridColGruppe.DataSource = Core.Gruppen.Select(item=>item.Name).ToList(); //get all items from ListBinding Gruppe
    }

    private void Produktpflege_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var v in Core.Produkte) //create a new line foreach Produkt in Datagrid
        {
            var gdvRow = new DataGridViewRow();

            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) //create cells
            {
                if (i == 2) //Gruppe needs to be a combobox
                    gdvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewComboBoxCell());
                else //all other are only text
                    gdvRow.Cells.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxCell());
            }

            gdvRow.Cells[0].Value = v.ID; //invisible for user
            gdvRow.Cells[1].Value = v.Name;
            gdvRow.Cells[2].Value = v.Gruppe.Name; //string with Gruppe-Name
            gdvRow.Cells[3].Value = v.Kohlenhydrate_je_100g;
            gdvRow.Cells[4].Value = v.Eiweiss_je_100g;
            gdvRow.Cells[5].Value = v.Fett_je_100g;
            gdvRow.Cells[6].Value = v.Alkoholgehalt_Prozent;
            gdvRow.Cells[7].Value = v.KCAL; //readonly

            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(gdvRow);
        }
    }
```

It cancels any change of the Gruppe in combobox with "System.FormatException: The DataGridViewComboBoxCell-Value is invalid." as well as if i just load the form and fill in the data.

FormDesigner:

```
 private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.gridColID = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gridColName = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gridColGruppe = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        this.gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gridColEiweiss_je_100g = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gridColFett_je_100g = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gridColKCAL = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.gruppeBindingSource = new System.Windows.Forms.BindingSource(this.components);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gruppeBindingSource)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.gridColID,
        this.gridColName,
        this.gridColGruppe,
        this.gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g,
        this.gridColEiweiss_je_100g,
        this.gridColFett_je_100g,
        this.gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent,
        this.gridColKCAL});
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 58);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(983, 192);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.dataGridView1.DataError += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventHandler(this.dataGridView1_DataError);
        // 
        // gridColID
        // 
        this.gridColID.HeaderText = "ID";
        this.gridColID.Name = "gridColID";
        this.gridColID.ReadOnly = true;
        this.gridColID.Visible = false;
        // 
        // gridColName
        // 
        this.gridColName.HeaderText = "Name";
        this.gridColName.Name = "gridColName";
        // 
        // gridColGruppe
        // 
        this.gridColGruppe.DataSource = this.gruppeBindingSource;
        this.gridColGruppe.DisplayStyle = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.ComboBox;
        this.gridColGruppe.HeaderText = "Gruppe";
        this.gridColGruppe.Name = "gridColGruppe";
        this.gridColGruppe.ValueMember = "Name";
        // 
        // gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g
        // 
        this.gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g.HeaderText = "Kohlenhydrate_je_100g";
        this.gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g.Name = "gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g";
        // 
        // gridColEiweiss_je_100g
        // 
        this.gridColEiweiss_je_100g.HeaderText = "Eiweiss_je_100g";
        this.gridColEiweiss_je_100g.Name = "gridColEiweiss_je_100g";
        // 
        // gridColFett_je_100g
        // 
        this.gridColFett_je_100g.HeaderText = "Fett_je_100g";
        this.gridColFett_je_100g.Name = "gridColFett_je_100g";
        // 
        // gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent
        // 
        this.gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent.HeaderText = "Alkoholgehalt_in_Prozent";
        this.gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent.Name = "gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent";
        // 
        // gridColKCAL
        // 
        this.gridColKCAL.HeaderText = "KCAL";
        this.gridColKCAL.Name = "gridColKCAL";
        this.gridColKCAL.ReadOnly = true;
        // 
        // gruppeBindingSource
        // 
        this.gruppeBindingSource.DataSource = typeof(Kohlenhydrate_Datenbank.Gruppe);
        // 
        // Produktpflege
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1007, 262);
        this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Produktpflege1";
        this.Text = "Produktpflege";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Produktpflege_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.gruppeBindingSource)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColID;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColName;
    private DataGridViewComboBoxColumn gridColGruppe;
    private BindingSource gruppeBindingSource;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColKohlenhydrate_je_100g;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColEiweiss_je_100g;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColFett_je_100g;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColAlkoholgehalt_in_Prozent;
    private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn gridColKCAL;
```

I'd be really happy if i could get this working within the next two weeks with your help. Please don't tell me to use WPF instead, because i need it to run in Windows Forms to support Windows XP as well.

Comment: `dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(Gruppe);` should be changed to `dataGridView1.Columns[2].ValueType = typeof(string)`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya this doesn't work for me either.the filled lines got no value filled in and no values in combobox, the next empty line got the values it should contain in combobox, but by selectiing one of them, my Application.Run(new form1()); crashes with "System.ArgumentException"